# Android timer how to?

Tags: android

I have a basic timer here that I'd like to call a method in every 2 seconds or so..

I'm trying to implement my timer but it gives me a "Unable to start activity ComponentInfo" error.

Here is my code:

```
public class AndroidTabLayoutActivity extends TabActivity {

Timer pollTimer;
TimerTask TestTimer;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    pollTimer = new Timer();

    pollTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(TestTimer, 1, 1000);

    TestTimer = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Timer tick!");
        }
    };
}
```

There must be something I'm doing wrong.

Any help would be fantastic, thank you!

Comment: did you declare ComponentInfo in your manifest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

> @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>       setContentView(R.layout.main);
>
> ```
> pollTimer = new Timer();
>
> TestTimer = new TimerTask() {
>     @Override
>     public void run() {
>         System.out.println("Timer tick!");
>     }
> };
> ```
>
> pollTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(TestTimer, 1, 1000); }

Answer (score 0):

The best example for you

Hope this help :D

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html